# Flask - Create index page with only the authorized route for user

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, python-decorators

I'm programming a dashboard with two roles (user & admin). I have a decorator called `requires_admin` which prevents simple user to access the page.

My problem is that I have an index page with all the routes listed and I want to only display the routes that are allowed for this particular user.

It means that I want to know which routes have a `requires_admin` decorator and which haven't.

Is that somehow possible?

Comment: Are you cutom created `required_admin` decorator ? or Do you use any third party plugin ?

Comment: @RajaSimon custom created

Comment: Oh well why don't you consider `flask-principle` it's having the option to check `current_user.has_role('Admin')` in template.

Answer (score 1):

**If you wish to use your custom roles, then when someone logs in, you can save their details including their role in flask session like this**

```
from flask import session as login_session
login_session['user_role'] = user.role #assuming you have queried your user object whose attributes include role
```

Then when rendering the template, you can pass the user role

```
user_role  = login_session['user_role']
return render_template('index.html', user_role= user_role)
```

Then in your template (am just using a link, but you can enclose a whole div)

```
{% if user_role == 'admin'%}
<a href ="/secretdash">Dashboard</a>
{%endif%}
```

**But I would highly recommend** you use flask-security (or as suggested in comments flask-principle which is one of the modules in flask-security). With flask-security/flask principle you can do the following

1) link for only logged in users

```
{% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
 <li> <a href="/firstdashboard"> Dashboard </a> </li>
{% endif %}
```

2) Link for users with only certain roles

```
{% if current_user.has_role('admin') %}
<li><a href="/secretdash">Secret Dash</a></li>
{% endif %}
```